# Access filters on splitform through query to report

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a splitform and what I want to do is open report on filter I use in this spltiform. What's important is that in this splitform you can do the correction of the row (you can't edit the previous row, but it creates two additional rows - one is negative and the other is to edit and I have one column which stores the ID of corrected row - CorrectedRowID). So I can't create report based on that table, so I created a query which groups this data by CorrectedRowID and it takes the last row of each ID so I have only the newest row of every ID. Then based on that query I created report.

On the splitform I have button which opens the report. But what I want is that when I have filter in this splitform and I click on the button Open Form it opens the report already on the filters. I have used this code in this button in VBA:

```
Private Sub Command282_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "tb_ewid_WNT1_raport", acViewPreview, , Me.filter

End Sub
```

When I create a normal report (not based on query) filter works great, but when I put some filter on the data in this splitform on one column it asks me for the value of the column on which I want to filter my data.

The query returns the newest rows of each ID.  For example:

| ID | Name | Quantity | Price | CorrectedRowID | IsCorrection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bread | 4 | 1,5 | 1 | No |
| 2 | milk | 3 | 2,3 | 2 | No |
| 3 | bread | -4 | 1,5 | 1 | Yes |
| 4 | bread | 11 | 1,5 | 1 | Yes |

In this case query will return this, so for each CorrectedRowID it returns the highest ID:

| ID | Name | Quantity | Price | CorrectedRowID | IsCorrection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | milk | 3 | 2,3 | 2 | No |
| 4 | bread | 11 | 1,5 | 1 | Yes |

I created the report based on this query. And I also created a button on splitform which uses the code I wrote up. When I filter my data and when I click on this button it asks me for the value for some column (it's not the same every time).  The values that it asks for are combo boxes which take the values from not the same table. The query uses JOIN.

Where did I make mistake?

Comment: Adapt your question with the following -> Add a `debug.print "Filter = " & Me.filter` in the button code and post the result, so we know exactly what's in there. Then show the SQL queries behind the reports

Comment: @ThomasG I added the code to wrote and nothing showed, it asks me for the value of one of the columns and opens the report (but the filters doesn't work)

Comment: How are you applying filter to form? Code works when report is based on table, not query? Edit question to show query. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for review.

Comment: I tested this scenario and it works.